# Can someone explain what the right side means? I'm confused about the notation, especially the {} brackets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs

This is asking for a combinatorial proof of $x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \brace k} (x)_k$. I am asking for help interpreting the right side.

Comment: I think that this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition) will be helpful. See the last line of the Definition section.

Comment: ${n\brace k}$ is notation for [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), the number of partitions of $n$ labeled elements into $k$ non-empty non-labelled parts.  Then $x\frac{k}{~}$ is notation for [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: With regards to a combinatorial proof of the identity, if we were to assume that $x$ were a positive integer, we'd have the left hand side counts the number of ways to put $n$ labeled balls into $x$ labeled boxes directly.  The right hand side counts the same but by first splitting up the balls into piles and then deciding which box to put each pile in and having broken into cases based on the number of piles used.  Extending to non-integer $x$, the metaphor breaks down a bit...

Comment: @JMoravitz Moreover, both sides of the equation are polynomials, and they coincide on all integers, so they must be equal as functions.

Answer (score 3):

By $\{n,k\}$, the authors almost certainly mean the [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) which are usually typeset as ${n\brace k}$.

By $x^{\underline{k}}$ the authors mean the [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $x^{\underline{k}} = (x-0)(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-(k-1))$.

This fact about stirling numbers is super well known, and basically says that they tell us how to change basis from the standard polynomial basis $x^n$ to the "falling" basis $x^{\underline{n}}$. You can find a proof in lots of places, like [here](https://planetmath.org/stirlingnumbersofthesecondkind).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the perfect answer I was looking for.  Your explanation was thorough and useful.  This way I can attempt my proof first and then look at the proof you posted, thank you again!!

Comment: Thanks @Mike! My usual way of typesetting the stirling numbers didn't work on mse for some reason... I had no idea `\brace` was an option! And @Regan, happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question, you should mark it as such by clicking the check mark to the left of the question so that other users know how to spend their time